# Pillow (PIL), python 3, How would I invert the colors of an image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, project, physics

I have learned the basics of the PIL library , and I need Ideas for my physics project. I have an idea that I was influenced by the instructor, how would I invert the colors of an image, for example an African tree frog. A reptile that has bright vibrant color, how would I go about inverting the colors of it on the opposite color spectrum?

Comment: what have you tried, and where did you get stuck? Generally it's a good idea to post a bit of your code, and either the error you're currently stuck on, or where you're getting results you don't expect, along with what you do expect to get.

Comment: If you haven't even figured out where to start yet, I'd say in broad strokes you'll need to open the image using PIL, convert the colorspace to hsv or hsl (hue - saturation - value/lightness), and invert the hue channel before saving it to a new image

Comment: as of right now, I have done almost everything that is mentioned in the introduction to the pillow library from tutorials point, I would like to get know the advanced side of the PIL library and apply more than just the basics.

Comment: please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70177765/edit) then and include the code you do have, and if possible strip out things unrelated to the question at hand (when in doubt leave it in though).